# Apple Mach-O Linker Error?

Tags: ios, linker-errors

Error :This is the error I am getting , I have delete REmenu files from project and imports from all files. Do'nt have any idea what to do about this error . No mistake  in code and tried all solutions where given .
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wRv.png)

Comment: "all solutions" = what?  What did you try?  The error means that you have a reference to `REMenu` and `REMenuItem` but they were never compiled.  What are they?

Comment: I am not having anything related to REMenu

Comment: You do, in MasterViewController.m.  Check that file.

Comment: NO , Nothing related to REMenu here man ..

Comment: Well, I had a similar issue when i worked with googleAdMob. I resolved it by removing all related frameworks and then adding them over again. Give it a try and see if it is gone.

Comment: It not worked for me , tried this now .

Comment: Why dont you give us more information by e.g. supplying the exact and complete error message from the linker?

Comment: Click on the "1" for picture .

Comment: Did you clean the project after you removed all the file references??

Comment: How to clean the project ?

Answer (score 0):

checked ones
build phase -> compile Resource-> import all .m files

build settings ->search paths -> remove path

clear and build project

Comment: architecture armv7s remove add try

Comment: Where is architecture armv7s ?

Comment: build setting -> architectures

Comment: No success , dude .. :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to build Settings -> Architectures

Then Select **Standard Architectures(armv7,armv7s)**

Now Remove **armv7s** from Valid Architectures

Clean your project and try